# Highchart drilldown dymanic

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, drilldown

How can I implement dynamic drilldown charts?
This is my problem :

- I have a list of series datas (pie) and I want to get data for clicked element from backend and after it, automat open drilldown.
  As an example:
  Stackoverflow and Google, both of them pies
  When I click on Stackoverflow chart, i want to get it's id and request on backend for anothers data and after that, open drilldown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to listen to the click event from a highcharts chart on Angular.

To do that you can set the events property of the series like:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
          events: {
            click: (pointClicked) => {
                // TODO: Implement here your logic
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how would i open from here drilldown ? Also...i can not acces from this type of function variables or functions (like this.getSomething() )

Comment: You can, you just need a reference to your context. you could define a variable like

const _this = this;

and then reference your function like 

_this.getSomething();. Or you can append on your ts where you create the config something like this.chartOptions.plotOptions.series.events = {click: (pointClicked) => {}} Then in that case you are in the same context

Comment: do you have Telegram ? If i would not resolve that tommorow, I would ask :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get and apply data in `drilldown` event. For example:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      drilldown: function(e) {
        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
          const chart = this;
          // Show the loading label
          chart.showLoading('Loading ...');

          fetch('...')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              chart.hideLoading();
              chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data);
            });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v2n5w0fu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown

Comment: In fetch request i need to pass authorization token, how can i do that cause we do not have acces to global variables ?

Comment: Hi @dunivivi, You should have access to global variables in the drilldown callback function. Otherwise, please adapt this live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line to show the problem.

Comment: thanks for your response. I edited exemple.

Comment: Ok, but you need to also share a link to it.

Comment: here you are, i also wrote comments where i stuck
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ovpnfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I see that you need access to the component, so use an arrow function and get `chart` reference from `e.target`. Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-qgtivi

Comment: could i contact you somehow ?

Comment: @dunivivi, I think that there is no better place to contact than here.

Comment: i have some troubles :))) https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ovpnfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts 
I posted my approach here, if you can check what i have done

Comment: also in mentioned link i wrote the problem i have got about xAxis

Comment: Your example doesn't work, so I can't reproduce the problem. Please mock a part of your data and adapt this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sL1t5gcx/ to show the problem.

Comment: something like that i tried...with hardcoded datas and it says Can not read properties of null xAxis. https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ovpnfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Dont know how to start it, sorry

Comment: It is working as expected with hardcoded data: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ydzfxa

Comment: sorry, but if you have a real-time request like this, function run before value assign https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-kcavjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Also, i figured that...if we fetch data and try to addSeriesAsDrilldown, e.point is null

Comment: That's because you have specified series in drilldown options which results in default drilldown behaviour. You can use the same approach as in the jsfiddle example or call `e.preventDefault()`. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-rpcpic